# Car radio cuts out the car will not start

Tags: starting, fuel-system, car

I have a Mitsubishi Gallant-2004. Just recently, while driving, the car radio will cut out then come back on. After about a minute of doing this it will stop working completely. Lights do not dim, car seems to run ok. However when I park and turn the car off it will not start again. I put a new battery in. A week later it does the same thing. This time I let the car sit for a couple of hours and it started. The car sat for a couple of days and the next time I drove it, it did the same thing. This did start happening after filling the gas tank. Any ideas as to what is causing this?

Comment: When you turn the key to start it again, does it make any noises (like a clicking or the sound of it trying to start)?

Comment: Exact same thing just happened to me. Battery terminal was just a little to loose. Cleaning with a wire brush helped.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad connection somewhere.

Clean the battery terminals.  Replace the connectors if they cannot tighten down enough to make a good solid connection.  Check that the grounds are tight and making a good connection.